# Как можно прервать работу цикла, в котором происходит работа объекта класса Robot?

Tags: циклы, java

В Java присутствует один интересный класс, который предоставляет управление курсором мыши и клавиатурой. Это класс Robot.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно прервать работу цикла, в котором происходит работа робота. Например, нажатием какой-нибудь кнопки на клавиатуре.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

class myFrame extends JFrame
{
private Robot robot;
private JButton bt1;
public myFrame()
{
    setTitle("Robot"); 
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(); 
    GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment
            .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice screen = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();

    try {

        robot = new Robot(screen);

    } catch (AWTException ex) {
    }

    bt1 = new JButton("Start");
    panel.add(bt1); 
    bt1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) // здесь и происходят все действие
                                            // с нашим роботом
            {
                robot.mouseMove(500, 500 + 15 * i); // двигаем мышку на
                robot.delay(300);                   // заданную координату

                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK); // нажимаем левую
                                                            // кнопку мыши

                robot.delay(300); // 300 миллисекундная пауза
                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK); // отжимаем
                                                                // левую
                                                                // кнопку
                                                                // мыши
                robot.delay(300);
                robot.keyPress('O'); // нажимаем кнопу 'O' с клавиатуры
                robot.keyRelease('O'); // отжимаем кнопу 'O' с клавиатуры
                robot.delay(300);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN); // нажимаем кнопу 'DOWN' с клавиатуры
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
            }
        }
    });

    Container pane = getContentPane(); 
    pane.add(panel); 
    pack();
   }
}

public class MyRobot {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    myFrame frame = new myFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Честно говоря сомневаюсь, что так правильно, но я бы посоветовал вынести обработчик кнопки в отдельный поток, а потом, по нажатию кнопки, "Stop", к примеру, останавливать этот поток.

Comment: А обычный бряк уже "не в моде", @delphist007 ?

Comment: Так в итоге и получится делать `break`, после того как у потока установили флаг `Interupted` (который нужно проверять).